# Converting PyQt4 QString to Python list

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have an array of PyQt4 strings stored in a variable `result` that looks like this:

```
{
    PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'src'): PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'http://assets.macys.com/navapp/img/misc/close_button.gif'), 
    PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'alt'): PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'Close')
}
```

That I want to convert into a python of image src and alt tags. I'm trying to use this command:

```
for i in result:
    src = str(i['src'])
    alt = str(i['alt'])
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ghosttest.py", line 32, in <module>
    print i['src']
KeyError: 'src'
```

How do I convert this to a regular python list?

Comment: what is `i` supposed to contain?

Comment: i is iterating through 'result' which is a series of the code in braces above.

Comment: OK, that's what I realized... after being puzzled for a while... next time try to keep the information in your question less ambiguous :) Anyway, then my answer has the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
for i in result:
    src = str(i[PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'src')])
    alt = str(i[PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'alt')])
```

it's because our dict keys are not Python strings but `QString` objects.

(NOTE: I'm assuming two `QString` objects containing the same string always have the same hash code and always compare equal—if not, it's a bad idea to use `QString`s as dictionary keys in the first place.)

This is assuming `result` is a `list` containing dictionaries in the form you demonstrated, e.g.:

```
result = [
    {
        PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'src'): PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'http://...'),
        PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'alt'): PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'bla'),
    },
    {
        PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'src'): PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'http://...'),
        PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'alt'): PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'bla'),
    },
    ....
]
```

**NOTE:**

If you need to work on that data a lot, you might want to convert the entire list of data to a pure-Python data structure (i.e. convert all `QString`s to `unicode` or `str`) and then work ont he resulting new data structure. You can still choose to keep the original one by just storing the converted structure in another variable, as you might have guessed.

**UPDATE:** (as per a comment)

in case your `QString` objects actually contain non-ASCII characters, you're out of luck just using `str()` to convert them to plain Python strings; instead, you need to convert them to `unicode` objects:

```
src = unicode(i[PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'src')])
```

if you then need to convert that into "raw" bytes:

```
src = src.encode('utf_8')  # or use whatever encoding you prefer instead of UTF-8 here
```

Comment: If I don't put quotes, it says `PyQt4 not defined`

Comment: And if I use quotes, it says `KeyError: "PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'src')"`

Comment: Please `import PyQt4` in that case. (or better yet, `from PyQt4.QtCore import QString` and use the `QString(...)` shorter form instead)

Comment: OK thanks! Gonna try that. Yes, `result` is a `list` and looks just like that!

Comment: In general, please understand how coding works—just trying with putting quotes here and there randomly to see if stuff just magically starts to work is a waste of your time...

Comment: Thanks for your help - I'm just beginning and a little in over my head. It's working, but throwing an error -     
`alt = str(i[PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'alt')])`
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Yeah... that's completely unrelated to your original question. Anyway, just try `unicode(...)` instead of `str(...)`, and if you need bytes then, just `.encode('utf_8')` from the `unicode` object.